# How to store multiple rows on database in Thinkphp

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, thinkphp

I want to store multiple rows in single submit button. This is cart page
Here i added just simple code. i want to store multiple rows in database

**HTML**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" name="project_form"  id="project_form" action="{url r="cart#prepare"}" method="post"> 
            {foreach from=$user item="user"}
                <div class="col-4 heads"> NAME </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name" value="{$user.user_name}" > </div>

                <div class="col-4 heads"> Email </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" value="{$user.email}" > </div>

                <div class="col-4 heads"> Mobile </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="cell" id="cell" placeholder="mobile no" value="{$user.mobile}" > </div>
            {/foreach}
                <div class="col-4 heads"> ADDRESS LINE 1 </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="address1" id="address1"  placeholder="address1" > </div>

                <div class="col-4 heads"> ADDRESS LINE 2 </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="address2" id="address2" > </div>

                <div class="col-4 heads"> CITY </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="city" > </div>

                <div class="col-4 heads"> STATE </div>
                <div class="col-8"> <input type="text" name="state" id="state"  placeholder="state" > </div>

            <input type="text" id="iinc" name="iinc" value="3">
```

Here i added screenshot of cart page.
[image]

Dont confuse with html. The doubt is here only. Yes in php function only.

```
public function prepare()
{
    if(!$GLOBALS['user_info'])
    {
        app_redirect(url("user#login"));
    }
    else
    {
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $iinc = $_REQUEST['iinc'];

        for($i=1; $i <= $iinc; $i++)
        {
            $order_id[$i] = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
            $Amount[$i]=$_REQUEST['amount'];

            $list = $GLOBALS['db']->query("insert into payment(name,order_id,amount) Values('".$name."','".order_id[$i]."','".$Amount[$i]."');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Can you tell me how many times your for loop inserted data in your db?

Comment: @JaykumarGondaliya its unlimited time, may be 4 time may be more than 10 times

Comment: Oh then how can i write this, Please help me @JayBlanchard

Comment: Dear brother first change loop code coz i seen here $order_id[0] & $Amount[$i] not set so.
please change it

Comment: @JoygiveKalai You can prepared statement to secure your query .

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code like that

```
$order_id=array();
 $Amount=array();
        for($i=0; $i < $iinc; $i++)
        {
            $order_id[$i] = mt_rand(100000, 999999);
            $Amount[$i]=$_REQUEST['amount'];

            $list = $GLOBALS['db']->query("insert into payment(name,order_id,amount) Values('".$name."','".order_id[$i]."','".$Amount[$i]."');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You made mistake in your `for loop`

**Check This**

```
for($i=1; $i > $iinc; $i++)
```

**It should be like this**

```
for($i=1; $i < $iinc; $i++)
```

**OR**

```
for($i=1; $i <= $iinc; $i++)
```

Comment: sorry here only the problem. in my file i put correctly